# WPF application on Touch Monitor

Tags: c#, wpf

My application has all mouse events and no touch events. I am trying to get touch working.

When I have my xaml as below; using UserControl touch works fine

```
<UserControl x:Class="MainGUI.MyDialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         IsManipulationEnabled="True"
         ManipulationStarting="Window_ManipulationStarting"
         ManipulationDelta="Window_ManipulationDelta"
         ManipulationInertiaStarting="Window_InertiaStarting"
        >
```

But few of my windows inherit from a class as below. In these windows even if I try and implement Window_ManipulationStarting, Window_ManipulationDelta and Window_InertiaStarting, touch functionality does not work.

```
<ig:iMyMain x:Class="MainGUI.MySecondDialog"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:ig="clr-namespace:iMyMain;assembly=iCommon
          mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="600"
         IsManipulationEnabled="True"
         ManipulationStarting="Window_ManipulationStarting"
         ManipulationDelta="Window_ManipulationDelta"
         ManipulationInertiaStarting="Window_InertiaStarting"                               
         >
```

iMyMain class is inherited from System.Windows.Controls.UserControl

Any ideas?

Comment: is "touch" see as a mouseclick?

Comment: Yes. That is what "Manipulation" does. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee649090(v=vs.100).aspx
and http://nui.joshland.org/2010/04/why-wont-wpf-controls-work-with-touch.html